# python Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is not found, special character in path

Tags: python, path, character, special-characters

following problem:
If I run the listed code in a path without special characters, then the code runs without any problems.
But I have an "ä" in a folder name, and the python scrip crashes.
Is there a solution to this problem?

```
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = dir_path + '/#...blended
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = os.environ['JAVA_HOME']
db2jcc = dir_path + '/#...blended
db2jcc_lic = dir_path + '/#...blended
jars = [db2jcc, db2jcc_lic]
class_name = 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver'
ibmTrustStore = dir_path + '/#...blended
ibmTrustStoreBMT = dir_path + '/#...blended
conn = 'jdbc:db2:/#...blended
connBMF = 'jdbc:db2:/'/#...blended
connCEDE ='jdbc:db2:/'/#...blended`
connDBD ='jdbc:db2:/'/#...blended
```

This code is OK for paths without German umlauts, but as soon as an umlaut, e.g. "ä" is contained in the path name, the following error occurs:

Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver is not found